# Clearing out a DOM node in angularjs directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following directive. I usually don't like posting too much code so that those attempting to answer the question can focus on the important parts, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, so I have to.

It's a directive that should repeat all the children of the element. The initial rendering works, but when I modify the list, things get messed up. For a usage example, see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R35J2/1/). Try removing an item to see what goes wrong.

```js
bigblind = window.bigblind || angular.module("bigblind",[]);

bigblind.directive("repeatInside", function(){
    var makeChildScope = function(scope, index, key, val, keyIdentifier, valIdentifier){
        childScope = scope.$new();
        childScope.index = index
        if (keyIdentifier) childScope[keyIdentifier] = index;
        childScope[valIdentifier] = val;
        childScope.first = (index == 0);
        return childScope
    };
    var ddo = {
        transclude:true,
        compile: function(element, attrs, transclude){
            return function($scope, $element, $attr){
                var expression = $attr.repeatInside;
                var match = expression.match(/^\s*(.+)\s+in\s+(.*?)$/)
                var lhs, rhs
                var keyIdentifier, valIdentifier, hashFnLocals = {};


                if(!match){
                    throw "Expected expression in form of '_item_ in _collection_[ track by _id_]' but got " + expression;
                }

                lhs = match[1];
                rhs = match[2];

                match = lhs.match(/^(?:([\$\w]+)|\(([\$\w]+)\s*,\s*([\$\w]+)\))$/);
                if (!match) {
                    throw "bad left hand side in loop";
                }
                valIdentifier = match[3] || match[1];
                keyIdentifier = match[2];

                $scope.$watch(rhs, function(newval, oldval) {
                    var childScope, index = 0

                    for (var child in $element.children){
                        child.remove();
                    }

                    if (angular.isArray(newval)){
                        for (index=0; index<newval.length; index++) {
                            childScope = makeChildScope($scope, index, index, newval[index], keyIdentifier, valIdentifier);
                            transclude(childScope, function(clone){
                                clone.scope = childScope;
                                $element.append(clone);
                            });
                        }
                    }else{
                        for (key in newval){
                            if (newval.hasOwnProperty(key) && !key[0] == "$") {
                                childScope = makeChildScope($scope, index, key, newval[key], keyIdentifier, valIdentifier);
                                index += 1;
                                transclude(childScope, function(clone){
                                    clone.scope = childScope;
                                    $element.append(clone);
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }, true);
            }   
        }
    };
    return ddo
})
```

Comment: There's something weird here that I can't wrap my head around... I'm going to post an answer instead of a comment so I can format my code better.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to get the children and remove them by taking `angular.element($element[0]).children()^`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is happening at `child.remove();`. You'll notice that your loop doesn't actually iterate over any children: `for (var child in $element.children)`

When I log the following expressions, I get some weird results

```
(a) console.log($element);
(b) console.log($element[0]);
(c) console.log(angular.element($element[0]));
```

Gives

```
(a) [dl, ready: function, toString: function, eq: function, push: function, sort: function…]
(b) <dl repeat-inside=​"word in dict">​…​</dl>​
(c) [dl, ready: function, toString: function, eq: function, push: function, sort: function…]
```

Furthermore, the API is actually `angular.element.children()` and not `angular.element.children`. But `$element` is an array and it has no DOM children. It's first element refers to the `<dl>` DOM element we are looking for though.

So I would expect `$element[0]` or `angular.element($element[0])` to give this to us as a proper [JQuery element](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element). But as you can see from those console logs, we just end up going in circles.

I hope someone can shed some light on this.